# How can I convert a date-like string eg "2014-08-18T03:29:12.000Z" to seconds?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two dates:

```
var now = new Date().valueOf();
var exp = expirationDate.valueOf();
if (exp - now > 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

However the expirationDate is in the following format:

```
expirationDate
"2014-08-18T03:29:12.000Z"
console.log(now)
1407125392136
console.log(expirationDate.valueOf())
2014-08-18T03:29:12.000Z
```

It was suggested to me that I could use valueOf() but that does not seem to work at all. Can anyone give me advice on how I can convert so I can compare with the present date time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expiration date is a string, not a native `Date` object.

Use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to convert the string to a `Date` object and then you can compare them. Like so:

```
var now = new Date().valueOf();
var exp = Date.parse(expirationDate).valueOf();
if (exp - now > 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this it will surely help you**

```
expirationDate.setMinutes(expirationDate.getMinutes() + 15);

seconds = Math.round(expirationDate - now)/1000;

var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
var remainingSeconds = Math.round( remainingSeconds );
```

Answer (score -1):

`getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds since the epoch - so you could compare by dividing by 1000 eg

```
var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000 ;
var exp = expirationDate.getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: It appears to be that `expirationDate` is a string, not a Date object so this won't work.